# how can I use moment in mongoose aggregate method?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, momentjs, aggregate

I have the following query in mongoose and need to use moment in "addFields" section. In this query it says "invalid date" if I cancel out " " and just write moment($message.createdAt).fromNow(), then it throws an error.
I actualy put moment in toJSON method of my Messenger model, however It does not work neither.

```
 const newConverSation = await Messenger.Messenger.aggregate([
    { $match: {
        users: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.userid)}
    },
    { 
        $sort: { 'updatedAt': -1,} 
    },
        {
      $group: {
        _id: { $setUnion: "$users" },
        message: { $first: "$$ROOT" },
      },
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            "last": moment("$message.createdAt").fromNow(),
        }
    },

    { 
        $sort: { 'message.createdAt':-1 } 
    },
  ])
```

Comment: Can you provide your schema code here.Cause as I see `last` field may be Date type and fromNow(); is return a string not Datetime type

Comment: You can't use an external function in that code.

Comment: @prasad_ is there any way to use multer in that operation tough?